# Percent errors using the arc cosine function trying to output 3 different numbers of percentages

Tags: visual-c++

I coded all of this but it will not output any of my percent errors i'm not quite sure where to put the percent? It is suppose to output 3 different numbers but I can't even get to the output because of this error i have no idea i tried changing everything to floats and and ints but the error message of % is overloading the function?

```
double dRandom()
{
    return double(rand()/RAND_MAX); 
}

int main()
{
    int loop_count=100, count=0;

    int result=0; 
    float x=dRandom(); 
    double y=dRandom(); 
    float arccos (float x);
    float function=0; 
    srand(time(NULL)); 

    for(int i=1; i<4;++i) 
    { 
        for (int k=1; k<= loop_count; ++k) 
        { 
            function= (x* arccos(x)-sqrt(1- pow(x,2)))%RAND_MAX;//this line is where i'm not sure how to add the percent sign in correctly 
        }  
    } 

    if(x<y)  
        cout<<result; 

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Whats the error message this is returning and can you please clarify what you're trying to achieve with the code?

Comment: error- '%' : illegal, left operand has type 'float' 
My code is suppose to be outputting 3 different percentages taking random numbers and applying towards my function of arc cosine

Comment: The `%` operator in C++ is the modulo (remainder).  It has nothing at all to do with percentages.

Comment: everywhere i looked up and found i have to use a percent "%" operator to get my outputs so i'm not sure now what operator to put in?

Answer (score 0):

If you want percentages, it should be this:
    function=(x* arccos(x)-sqrt(1- pow(x,2)))/RAND_MAX*100;

It should be the thing you want.